# Backbutton webbrowser + expired content = refresh

Tags: .net, caching

I have the following in my .Net code:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

When the users use the back button of Internet Explorer, they get a content expired warning. They need to hit F5 to reload the page.

Can I make adjustments so there is no caching, but with an automatic refresh so the warning isn't displayed?

Regards,

M.

Comment: What HTTP headers does your code produce?

Comment: It produces Cache-Control: no-cache.

Answer (score 1):

That 'Content Expired' warning usually comes up when the page attempting to be reloaded was the result of a `POST` request. For normal `GET` requests in the history, the browser would simply issue another request for it.

This is one reason why the Post-Redirect-Get pattern is such a good pattern to use for `POST` requests: The Redirect removes the actual POST result page from the browser's history, replacing it with the page you redirect them to. (Actually, it doesn't remove anything at all - when the browser gets the 'redirect', it simply puts the page it was redirected to into the history instead of the original `POST` page)

This should go with the principle of 'idempotent gets', where your `GET` requests should never do anything destructive (so that the default behavior of web browsers simply re-requesting those GET pages from history isn't a bad thing.

Comment: Hmmm certainly a good alternative, but a reasonable impact on our system. I was hoping on a magical header combination, but I'm afraid that's not possible.